# Complex Integral over a circle 4

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

Let $r>0, z_0\,\epsilon \,\mathbb C$ and $ z_1$ be a point in the open disc $D_r(z_0)$. For $k\,\epsilon \, \mathbb Z$ show that

$\int_{|z-z_0|=r}(z-z_1)^k dz= 0 $ when $k\, \neq \, -1$

and

$\int_{|z-z_0|=r}(z-z_1)^k dz= 2\pi i $ when $k\, = \, -1$.

Second part is direct from Cauchy Integral formula. No idea about how to do the first. Any hints/ideas?

Comment: For $k \neq -1$, $(z-z_1)^k$ has a primitive.

Comment: Sorry if I sound dumb but what's a primitive?

Comment: $f$ is a primitive of $g$ if ($f$ is differentiable and) $f' = g$.

Answer (score 1):

For $\;k\ge 0\;$ the integrand $\;(z-z_0)^k\;$ is a polynomial and thus holomorphic every where, so that integral is zero.

For $\;k<-1\;$ : for simplicity put $\;m=-k\;$ , so

$$(z-z_0)^k=\frac1{(z-z_0)^m}$$

But the rightmost expression above is just the Laurent Series of itself around $\;z_0\;$ , and thus clearly its residue at $\;z_0\;$ is zero (since $\;m=-k>1\;$ !) , so by Cauchy's Teorem (the integral one with residues) the integral is zero.

Comment: But it says $(z-z_1)^k$?

Comment: Good point, @pseudogeek: I misread that, but the argument is, mutatis mutandis, *exactly the same* as $\;z_1\in D_r(z_0)\;$ ...